# jq selection of an attribute value based on another attribute's length and store that value in a text file

Tags: arrays, json, conditional-statements, jq

I am using jq and want to select the value of an attribute from a large json file based on the condition that an another array is not empty. If that is empty, then we should ignore the value and check the next attribute, and so on. We also would like to store all values that fulfill the non-empty array condition into a text file, one value per line and unquoted.

For example, I have a large json file (16+ GB) having **200k** plus entries as below:

```
{"one": "Some string", "two": "A", "three": []}
{"one": "Some string", "two": "B", "three": [{"a": 1,"b": 2}]}
{"one": "Some string", "two": "C", "three": []}
```

Specifically, I want to select the values of **only those** `"two"` attributes for which the value of array `"three"` is **not empty**. So, in the above example, only the value **"B"** should be returned, and all other values should be **ignored**. I also need to store all such values returned (like **"B"** in the above case) into a text file, one per line and unquoted.

Can't seem to figure out how to do it. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The input you show isn't valid (objects must be key/value pairs); and what is the expected output? The value of `two`, one per line? Quoted, unquoted?

Comment: It is a large json file containing object in the format I stated in my question. I want each value of the attribute two one per line and unquoted only where the attribute three is not null.

Comment: 1. Please note that`null` is a JSON value, distinct from `[]`, so your attempted clarification just muddies the water.  2. Please give a more comprehensive example, including expected output, showing what is expected if the "B" value occurs more than once if that is possible.

Comment: I am sorry about the lack of my knowledge about JSON format. Yes I want all values in the attribute "two" when there is some value in attribute "three".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the input as originally shown in the Q, is not valid JSON, and so some alterations or corrections would have to be made if jq is to be used in a straightforward way.

Assuming these changes have been made, the following illustrates an efficient approach that avoids "slurping" the input:

##### Invocation: jq -rnf program.jq input.json

```
[inputs | select(.three != []) | .two] | unique[]
```

This produces the distinct values, sorted.

#### An alternative

The above solution involves collecting all the relevant .two values in an array.  If that is unsatisfactory,
one alternative would be to pipe the stream of the relevant .two values to `sort`:

```
< input.json jq -rn 'inputs | select(.three != []) | .two' | sort -u > two.txt
```

Comment: @MuhammadShakeel - It would help if you could fix your question, by giving valid JSON and by clarifying your requirements. Please also use the appropriate vocabulary, e.g. if by "empty" you mean an empty array, then please say so.

Comment: Good. I’ve upvoted the Q, and trust you will find this answer not only works but also meets your requirements or at least provides enough guidance.

Comment: @MuhammadShakeel Both solutions work for your example input: [one](https://jqplay.org/s/MbWC6uGOje), [two](https://jqplay.org/s/9zOJL8Ep5v). So, if you're seeing something different, you have to provide example input that corresponds to your real input.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this (see [playground](https://jqplay.org/s/N0_JBHokOW)):

```sh
jq --raw-output 'if (.three | length > 0) then .two else empty end'
```

and to redirect output to a file:

```sh
jq --raw-output 'if (.three | length > 0) then .two else empty end' > outfile
```

This assumes valid input, so the playground example uses an array of strings.

Comment: The without slurping answer produces an error: jq: error (at <stdin>:2): Cannot index array with string "three" exit status 5

Comment: @MuhammadShakeel Did you remove `--slurp`? You'd see that error if you don't remove it.

Answer (score 2):

If the input file is large, you should process the elements one after the other instead of reading them into an array at once with `--slurp` and processing them together. Otherwise, memory problems may occur.

#### corrected input

```json
{"one": "Some string", "two": "A", "three": []}
{"one": "Some string", "two": "B", "three": [{"a": 1},{"b": 2}]}
{"one": "Some string", "two": "C", "three": []}
```

#### command

`jq -r 'select(.three | length > 0) | .two' < file_in.json > file_out.json`

#### output

```
B
```

Comment: @Muhammad: input comes from `file_in.json` and is stored in `file_out.json`

Comment: @Muhammad: For the command to work, you must save the input data to `file_in.json`. If you see the output on the console (without redirection to `file_out.json`), you may lack permission to save data to `file_out.json`

Comment: ok ... then if the file redirection does not work on your machine for whatever reason, here is your example using `echo` instead: `echo '{"one": "Some string", "two": "A", "three": []}{"one": "Some string", "two": "B", "three": [{"a": 1},{"b": 2}]}{"one": "Some string", "two": "C", "three": []}' | jq -r 'select(.three | length > 0) | .two'`